# Как выполнить копирование в буфер обмена при помощи Protractor'а?

Tags: javascript, test-automation, jasmine, protractor

Есть веб-текстовый редактор, в который во время теста необходимо сделать вставку текста из буфер обмена. Подскажите, как можно это сделать в синтаксисе `jasmine`? Комбинации <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> срабатывают как надо, но <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> не работает. Тестирую с помощью `Protractor`.

```
var Copy = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "c");
Copy.perform();
```

Еще пробовал так:

```
function () {

    function setClipboardContents(content) {
        var clipboard = gui.Clipboard.get();
        clipboard.set(content, 'text');
    };

    TextArea.sendKeys('123'); 
    setClipboardContents('fgh');
    Paste.perform();
    browser.sleep('3000');
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что копирование не выполняется мгновенно. Если  после посылки сочетания Ctrl+C попробовать руками вставить текст в блокнот, то вставится то, что нужно, или нет?

Comment: в том то и дело, что при послке ctrl+C в строку редактора попадает "C", а буфер остается пустым, в случае если в буфере есть что то, то оно и вставляется после ctrl+v

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, твоя правка делает тему несоответсвующей вопросу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

В наших проектах, без проблем работает копирование/вставка через `protractor.Key.chord()`. Например, вот кусок кода из рабочего теста:

```
browser.actions()
    .click(aboutPage.licenseText)
    .sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "a"))
    .sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "c"))
    .perform();
```

Правда, у нас существуют проблемы с работой горячих клавиш в хроме через `chromedriver`, поэтому подобные тесты мы запускаем на FF и других браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий код:

```
browser.executeScript("document.execCommand('copy', false, null)");
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v").perform();
```